# Error on Map Style Tutorial

Tags: java, error, geotools

Trying to follow the Map Style tutorial, as the functionality of changing color of objects selected is one thing I am trying to add to my project. However, after running the code from the tutorial I get the following error:

Tutorial: http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/map/style.html

Note: My code and pom.xml is exactly as shown in the tutorial (I had to tweak a few things, also I am using **14-SNAPSHOT**).

**Edit: Code:**

```
package com.mycompany.mapselection;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JToolBar;

import org.geotools.data.FileDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.FileDataStoreFinder;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureIterator;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureSource;
import org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.ReferencedEnvelope;
import org.geotools.map.FeatureLayer;
import org.geotools.map.Layer;
import org.geotools.map.MapContent;
import org.geotools.styling.FeatureTypeStyle;
import org.geotools.styling.Fill;
import org.geotools.styling.Graphic;
import org.geotools.styling.Mark;
import org.geotools.styling.Rule;
import org.geotools.styling.Stroke;
import org.geotools.styling.Style;
import org.geotools.styling.StyleFactory;
import org.geotools.styling.Symbolizer;
import org.geotools.swing.JMapFrame;
import org.geotools.swing.data.JFileDataStoreChooser;
import org.geotools.swing.event.MapMouseEvent;
import org.geotools.swing.tool.CursorTool;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;
import org.opengis.feature.type.GeometryDescriptor;
import org.opengis.filter.Filter;
import org.opengis.filter.FilterFactory2;
import org.opengis.filter.identity.FeatureId;

import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.LineString;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.MultiLineString;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.MultiPolygon;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class MapSelection {

    private StyleFactory sf = CommonFactoryFinder.getStyleFactory();
    private FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();

    private enum GeomType { POINT, LINE, POLYGON };

    private static final Color LINE_COLOR = Color.BLUE;
    private static final Color FILL_COLOR = Color.CYAN;
    private static final Color SELECTED_COLOR = Color.YELLOW;
    private static final float OPACITY = 1.0f;
    private static final float LINE_WIDTH = 1.0f;
    private static final float POINT_SIZE = 10.0f;

    private JMapFrame mapFrame;
    private SimpleFeatureSource featureSource;

    private String geometryAttributeName;
    private GeomType geometryType;

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {

        MapSelection me = new MapSelection();

        File file = JFileDataStoreChooser.showOpenFile("shp", null);

        if (file == null) 
            return;

        me.displayShapefile(file);
    }

    public void displayShapefile(File file) throws Exception {
        FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);
        featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();
        setGeometry();

        /*
         * Create the JMapFrame and set it to display the shapefile's features
         * with a default line and colour style
         */
        MapContent map = new MapContent();
        map.setTitle("Feature selection tool example");
        Style style = createDefaultStyle();
        Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureSource, style);
        map.addLayer(layer);
        mapFrame = new JMapFrame(map);
        mapFrame.enableToolBar(true);
        mapFrame.enableStatusBar(true);

        /*
         * Before making the map frame visible we add a new button to its
         * toolbar for our custom feature selection tool
         */
        JToolBar toolBar = mapFrame.getToolBar();
        JButton btn = new JButton("Select");
        toolBar.addSeparator();
        toolBar.add(btn);

        /*
         * When the user clicks the button we want to enable
         * our custom feature selection tool. Since the only
         * mouse action we are intersted in is 'clicked', and
         * we are not creating control icons or cursors here,
         * we can just create our tool as an anonymous sub-class
         * of CursorTool.
         */
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            //@Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                mapFrame.getMapPane().setCursorTool(
                        new CursorTool() {

                            @Override
                            public void onMouseClicked(MapMouseEvent ev) {
                                selectFeatures(ev);
                            }
                        });
            }
        });

        /**
         * Finally, we display the map frame. When it is closed
         * this application will exit.
         */
        mapFrame.setSize(800, 800);
        mapFrame.setVisible(true);
    }




    void selectFeatures(MapMouseEvent ev) {

        System.out.println("Mouse click at: " + ev.getWorldPos() );

        Point screenPos = ev.getPoint();
        Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(screenPos.x-2, screenPos.y-2, 5, 5);

        AffineTransform screenToWorld = mapFrame.getMapPane().getScreenToWorldTransform();
        Rectangle2D worldRect = screenToWorld.createTransformedShape(screenRect).getBounds2D();
        ReferencedEnvelope bbox = new ReferencedEnvelope(
                worldRect, mapFrame.getMapContent().getCoordinateReferenceSystem());

        Filter filter = ff.intersects(ff.property(geometryAttributeName), ff.literal(bbox));

        try {
            SimpleFeatureCollection selectedFeatures = 
                    featureSource.getFeatures(filter);

            SimpleFeatureIterator iterator = selectedFeatures.features();
            Set<FeatureId> IDs = new HashSet<>();

            try {

                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    SimpleFeature feature = iterator.next();
                    IDs.add(feature.getIdentifier());

                    System.out.println("    " + feature.getIdentifier());
                }
            } finally {
                iterator.close();
            }

            if (IDs.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("  no feature selected");
            }

            displaySelectedFeatures(IDs);

        } catch (IOException | NoSuchElementException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(MapSelection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void displaySelectedFeatures(Set<FeatureId> IDs) {
        Style style;

        if (IDs.isEmpty())
            style = createDefaultStyle();
        else 
            style = createSelectedStyle(IDs);

        Layer layer = mapFrame.getMapContent().layers().get(0);
        ((FeatureLayer) layer).setStyle(style);
        mapFrame.getMapPane().repaint();
    }

    private Style createDefaultStyle() {
        Rule rule = createRule(LINE_COLOR, FILL_COLOR);

        FeatureTypeStyle fts = sf.createFeatureTypeStyle();
        fts.rules().add(rule);

        Style style = sf.createStyle();
        style.featureTypeStyles().add(fts);

        return style;
    }

    private Style createSelectedStyle(Set<FeatureId> IDs) {
        Rule selectedRule = createRule(SELECTED_COLOR, SELECTED_COLOR);
        selectedRule.setFilter(ff.id(IDs));

        Rule otherRule = createRule(LINE_COLOR, FILL_COLOR);
        otherRule.setElseFilter(true);

        FeatureTypeStyle fts = sf.createFeatureTypeStyle();
        fts.rules().add(selectedRule);
        fts.rules().add(otherRule);

        Style style = sf.createStyle();
        style.featureTypeStyles().add(fts);
        return style;
    }

    private Rule createRule(Color outlineColor, Color fillColor) {
        Symbolizer symbol = null;
        Fill fill = null;
        Stroke stroke = sf.createStroke(ff.literal(outlineColor), ff.literal(LINE_WIDTH) );

        switch (geometryType) {
            case POLYGON:
                fill = sf.createFill(ff.literal(fillColor), ff.literal(OPACITY) );
                symbol = sf.createPolygonSymbolizer(stroke, fill, geometryAttributeName);
                break;
            case LINE:
                symbol = sf.createLineSymbolizer(stroke, geometryAttributeName);
                break;
            case POINT:
                fill = sf.createFill(ff.literal(fillColor), ff.literal(OPACITY) );

                Mark mark = sf.getCircleMark();
                mark.setFill(fill);
                mark.setStroke(stroke);

                Graphic graphic = sf.createDefaultGraphic();
                graphic.graphicalSymbols().clear();
                graphic.graphicalSymbols().add(mark);
                graphic.setSize(ff.literal(POINT_SIZE));

                symbol = sf.createPointSymbolizer(graphic, geometryAttributeName);
                break;
        }

        Rule rule = sf.createRule();
        rule.symbolizers().add(symbol);

        return rule;
    }

    private void setGeometry() {
        GeometryDescriptor geomDesc = featureSource.getSchema().getGeometryDescriptor();
        geometryAttributeName = geomDesc.getLocalName();

        Class<?> clazz = geomDesc.getType().getBinding();

        if (Polygon.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz) || 
                MultiPolygon.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
            geometryType = GeomType.POLYGON;

        } else if (LineString.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz) ||
                MultiLineString.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {

            geometryType = GeomType.LINE;
        } else {
            geometryType = GeomType.POINT;
        }
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>MapSelection</artifactId>
    <version>14-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MapSelection</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
            <version>14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-epsg-hsql</artifactId>
            <version>14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
            <version>14.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central.maven.org</id>
            <name>Central Maven repository</name>
            <url>http://central.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>


        <repository>
            <id>geosolutions</id>
            <name>geosolutions repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.geo-solutions.it/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>osgeo</id>
            <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
            <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>boundless</id>
            <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>
</project>
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileFeatureSource.getReaderInternal(ShapefileFeatureSource.java:336)
at org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileFeatureStore.getReaderInternal(ShapefileFeatureStore.java:126)
at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getReader(ContentFeatureSource.java:634)
at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.features(ContentFeatureCollection.java:173)
at com.mycompany.mapselection.App.selectFeatures(App.java:167)
at com.mycompany.mapselection.App$1$1.onMouseClicked(App.java:132)
at org.geotools.swing.event.DefaultMapMouseEventDispatcher.mouseClicked(DefaultMapMouseEventDispatcher.java:99)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:269)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:269)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6519)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4501)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: You say that your "code and pom.xml is exactly as shown in the tutorial" yet also say "I had to tweak a few things, also I am using 14-SNAPSHOT".  Please include code snippets within your question that demonstrate precisely what you tried and where you are stuck.  Many potential answerers will not follow links to track down question details.

Comment: Ok, but the 'tweaking' was just to get the dependencies working, since the tutorial uses 2.7 snapshot....

Comment: Probably just bitrotted with the various changes. Does it work if you use 2.7? Maybe you can ask on the geotools users' list: http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/welcome/support.html

Comment: I can confirm this is a bug - https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-5262

Comment: Is there a workaround I can implement that does something similar? (for lines mostly).

Comment: this bug is now fixed.